# Will a JsonDocument be automatically disposed if it is passed in as a parameter to a controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, idisposable

I am setting up an API to accept notifications from a web hook that does not provide a uniform shape for the objects. I know of a few common properties that will help me correctly route the notifications but not much more than that. My current solution is to accept a `JsonDocument` as the argument in my action method; however, I want to make sure I'm correctly disposing these. My code presently looks like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("notify")]
public IActionResult ReceiveNotification(JsonDocument notification)
{
    // Grab some information from the JsonDocument...
    notification.Dispose(); // Is it necessary to call this?
    return Ok("All done!");
}
```

Will `notification` be automatically disposed somehow or do I need to do it myself?

Docs [How to use a JSON document...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?source=recommendations&pivots=dotnet-7-0#use-jsondocument) don't cover using it as input to an action, but highlight importance of `Dispose` somewhere. I guess the other way to ask the question is if model binding "transfer lifetime ownership and dispose responsibility" to my action's code?

Comment: Why does your model need to be disposed? That seems odd

Comment: @DanielA.White because that class is `IDisposable` and docs strongly remind to do so.

Answer (score 0):

*<< Will a JsonDocument be automatically disposed if it is passed in as a parameter to a controller action*

Short answer is NO. GC will collect it once it go out of scope (if there is nothing holds onto it).

Best practice is Disposing all the disposable instances before they go out of scope.

You can use `notification` in a `using` statement to make sure it's disposed before it goes out of scope.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("notify")]
public IActionResult ReceiveNotification(JsonDocument notification)
{
    using (notification)
    {
        // Grab some information from the JsonDocument...
        return Ok("All done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also one should not dispose objects that their don't own. And to me the question is really "does my action *own* that parameter (and hence is responsible for disposing) or something else is responsible for it outside my code (and hence my code can't dispose it)"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: GC will collect it once it go out of scope (if there is nothing holds onto it). Yes I agree, it shouldn't dispose objects that they don't own. However, in this case API implementation method owns the JsonDocument object right? I assume this will be called as a WebAPI call..

Comment: I don't know who owns the JsonDocument (or any action's paramters) here - which is why I've updated Q with details and interested in the answer (i.e. [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) does not have any info on how `IDisposable` objects handled... which is a sign that action's code is responsible to dispose its parameters)

Comment: Q tags says it's a asp.net-core-webapi. If that's the case this method owns JsonDocument instance.